# Trying to add space to my fedora 31 VM on Virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, fedora

I'm trying to add space to my fedora31 virtual machine I've followed some tutorials to do so but my virtual machine still doesn't have the added space. The tutorials used the Virtual Box configuration to add space and the GParted to alloc the memory to the correct sda.

[image]

As you can see above the sda2 does have the added space but my root doesn't. Does anyone know how to "transfer" the free space to the root?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to expand the logical volume and the filesystem.

Try somthing like

```
lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-root
```